# How to create a row for every day in a date range(til the end of year) using while loop in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want the same condition to be copied until the end of the year. I mean add a row "every day" until '2023-12-31' Like second and third rows.
how to write query

[image]

Comment: And what would you expect to see in all the non-date fields for those rows, such as `LOGICALREF` and `EXPLANAITION`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways to generate a range of dates (aside from recursive CTE). In SQL Server 2016+:

```
DECLARE @d date = GETDATE();

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, rn, @d)
FROM
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE(',',365),',')
) AS x(rn)
WHERE rn < DATEDIFF(DAY,@d,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@d)+1,1,1));
```

In SQL Server 2022 (or Azure SQL Database):

```
DECLARE @d date = GETDATE();

SELECT d = DATEADD(DAY,value,@d) 
  FROM 
  GENERATE_SERIES(1,
    DATEDIFF(DAY,@d,
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())+1,1,1)));
```

If you want a recursive CTE (or are using an ancient version of SQL Server):

```
DECLARE @d date = GETDATE();

;WITH d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, @d)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, d) FROM d
    WHERE d < DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@d)+1,1,1))
)
SELECT d FROM d
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366);
```